# SQL Query for Last Years Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of data that used to come prepopulated with two separate data points( current and last years) for three headers (Sales, Units, and # of Warehouses.  For some reason the vendor no longer supports this and we're trying to figure out a way to populate the data ourselves with only the "current" column.  It looks something like this:

| Date | Venue | WH # | Item | Dollar Sales | Unit Sales | Warehouses Selling |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5/26/2019 | Abby | 10 | Apple | $40,345.00 | 58 | 23 |
| 5/26/2019 | Bobby | 20 | HP | $19,567.00 | 32 | 57 |
| 5/26/2020 | Charlie | 20 | HP | $39,764.00 | 87 | 121 |
| 5/26/2020 | Egad | 10 | Apple | $75,347.00 | 89 | 98 |

I would want columns that said Dollar Sales Last Year, Unit Sales Last Year, Warehouses Selling Last year.  I've tried doing this in excel but it seems to only work by month rather than the same date so I'm trying it in SQL Server.  However, I haven't touched SQL in about 5 years so I'm very rusty and don't really know where to start the calculation.  So far I have tried to create a column based on date ranges which kind of works but the problem is the dates are hardcoded in and wouldn't really be sustainable long term if I have to go in and change everything every time someone wants a report.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edited for table data:

| Venue | Dollar Sales | LY- Dollar Sales | Unit Sales | LY-Unit Sales | Warehouses Selling | LY- Warehouse Selling |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | $40,345.00 |  | 58 |  | 23 |  |
| HP | $19,567.00 |  | 32 |  | 57 |  |
| HP | $39,764.00 | $19,567 | 87 | 32 | 121 | 57 |
| Apple | $75,347.00 | $40,345 | 89 | 58 | 98 | 23 |

Comment: can you share expected output for above data?

Comment: Date Venue WH # Item Dollar Sales Dollar Sales Year Ago Unit Sales Unit Sales Year Ago Warehouses Selling Warehouses Selling Year Ago
5/26/2019 Abby 10 Apple $40,345.00  58  23 
5/26/2019 Bobby 20 HP $19,567.00  32  57 
5/26/2020 Charlie 20 HP $39,764.00 $19,567.00 87 32 121 57
5/26/2020 Egad 10 Apple $75,347.00 $40,345.00 89 58 98 23

Can't figure out how to format to a table, but basically after each data column their should be a column for last year with the previous years data.

Comment: Please click the edit button on your question above and add a table similar to the table you provided above with your expected output. Pasting it in the comments is difficult to read.

Comment: What is the relationship here?  Is it on the WH# and Item - just the WH# - or something else?  There are a couple of approaches - use a CTE to identify previous years values and then in the outer query - query for current year and join to previous year based on the key values.  Or - query for current year and use a CROSS/OUTER APPLY to query for previous years data - or, use a derived table for previous year (same concept as CTE).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The relationship would be on the date and the warehouse number yes.  What I am trying to do is have a column after each "data" set for units, dollars, and warehouses, giving me the information from last year.  Ideally, I want it to be smart so that is 2022 is the current year, 2021 would be last year, and if 2023 is the current year, 2022 would be the last year.  This used to be doable with the raw data we got from our vendor and some pivot charts but now they no longer provide the "last year" columns.